# Existence of chain homotopy from Dummit and Foote Chapter 17 Proposition 5

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

On Page 782 in Abstract Algebra by Dummit Foote, they claim that we may inductively define $R$-module homomorphisms $s_n : P_n \to P'_{n+1}$ such that $f_n = d'_{n+1} s_n + s_{n-1} d_n$, but never show how this is done.

I worked out exercise 4, but this just has us show that chain homotopic maps induce the same maps on homology (which is used near the end of the proof).

**How are they coming up with the maps $s_n$?**

---

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

First rewrite equation (17.10) as $d'_{n+1} s_n = f_n - s_{n-1} d_n$. The right side is a map 
$$\underbrace{f_n - s_{n-1} d_n}_{g_n} : P_n \to P'_n
$$ 
which we already know: $f_n$ and $d_n$ are given, and $s_{n-1}$ is given by induction.

On the left side, $d'_{n+1} : P'_{n+1} \to P'_n$ is given.

We need to find $s_n : P_n \to P'_{n+1}$ so that the equation $d'_{n+1} s_n = g_n$ holds. That is exactly what the definition of a projective module tells us we can do.